# Finding the general solution of the system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the general solution of the system

$$
        x=\begin{pmatrix}
        2 & -1  \\
        3 & -2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}x'
$$

The problem is I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are both equal to $0$. I am confused.

How do I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You made a mistake, clearly $\left(1,\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right)$ is an eigenpair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$c(\lambda) = (\lambda -2)(\lambda + 2) + 3 = \lambda^2 - 1.$$
The eigenvalues are $\lambda = \pm 1$.  Can you do the rest?

Comment: Yes I will. Thanks a lot. How come I messed it up I do not know

Comment: Relax. It's all part of the learning game.